# Can't get a plot from piecewise parametric function

Tags: plotting, syntax

I can't seem get a 3D plot from `r[t]`. Any suggestions?

```
r[t] = 
  Piecewise[{
   {{7 t, 0, 4 (1 + Cos[t])}, 0 <= t <= π}, 
   {{5 Cos[t - 3 π/2] + 7*π, 3 Sin[t - 3 π/2] + 3, 0}, π < t <= 2 π},
   {{7*π + 3*Cos[t - 3 π/2], 2*3 - 3 + 3*Sin[t - 3 π/2], 2/(3 π) (t - 2 π)^2}, 
     2 π < t <= 4 π},
   {{7 π - 5 (t - 4 π), 6 + 4 ((t - 4 π)/π)^3, 2 - 1/π t^2 + 10 t - 22 π}, 
     4 π < t <= 5 π},
   {{-3 t + 17 π, 10, 2 - 972 π + 540 t - (99 t^2)/π + (6 t^3)/π^2}, 
     5 π < t <= 6 π},
   {{-π - 3 Sin[t], 9/40 (1/3 (20 + 18 π) - t)^2, 3 Cos[t] - 1}, 6 π < t <= 8 π},
   {{-25 π + 25 t - (19 t^2)/(4 π) + t^3/(4 π^2), 
     -(25/2) (140 - 132 π + 27 π^2) + (15 (80 - 74 π + 15 π^2) t)/(2 π) - 
      (3 (180 - 164 π + 33 π^2) t^2)/(8 π^2) - ((-50 + 45 π - 9 π^2) t^3)/(20 π^3), 
     1058 - (360 t)/π + (81 t^2)/(2 π^2) - (3 t^3)/(2 π^3)}, 
     8 π < t <= 10 π}}]
```

Comment: `r[t_] := (* stuff *)`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: `[Pi]` is not a valid character.  A function definition is of the form `r[t_] := ....`, and so forth.  You apparently do not know the basics of *Mathematica*, so it will be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: I don't see what anything has to do with a `3D Plot`... and so on.

Comment: @David, the backslashes do not display in Markdown, so you're not seeing them, but OP did enter `\[Pi]`.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed code:

```
r[t_] := Piecewise[{{{7 t, 0, 4 (1 + Cos[t])}, 
     0 <= t <= π}, {{5 Cos[t - 3 π/2] + 7*π, 
      3 Sin[t - 3 π/2] + 3, 0}, π < t <= 
      2 π}, {{7*π + 3*Cos[t - 3 π/2], 
      2*3 - 3 + 3*Sin[t - 3 π/2], 2/(3 π) (t - 2 π)^2}, 
     2 π < t <= 4 π}, {{7 π - 5 (t - 4 π), 
      6 + 4 ((t - 4 π)/π)^3, 
      2 - 1/π t^2 + 10 t - 22 π}, 
     4 π < t <= 5 π}, {{-3 t + 17 π, 10, 
      2 - 972 π + 540 t - (99 t^2)/π + (6 t^3)/π^2}, 
     5 π < t <= 6 π}, {{-π - 3 Sin[t], 
      9/40 (1/3 (20 + 18 π) - t)^2, 3 Cos[t] - 1}, 
     6 π < t <= 
      8 π}, {{-25 π + 25 t - (19 t^2)/(4 π) + 
       t^3/(4 π^2), -(25/2) (140 - 132 π + 
          27 π^2) + (15 (80 - 74 π + 
            15 π^2) t)/(2 π) - (3 (180 - 164 π + 
            33 π^2) t^2)/(8 π^2) - ((-50 + 45 π - 
            9 π^2) t^3)/(20 π^3), 
      1058 - (360 t)/π + (81 t^2)/(2 π^2) - (3 t^3)/(2 \
π^3)}, 8 π < t <= 10 π}}];

ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 30 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]